# Redirection Issue With Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, frameworks

I am Uresh.I have issue with page redirection with server.(LINUX SHARED SERVER)

I have front-end of web site.
I have superadmin panel.
I have developer panel.
Means three types of users will use my site.
This is my directory path.

CONTROLLERS

> -> application\controllers\  = front end controllers
>
> -> application\controllers\admin = superadmin controllers
>
> -> application\controllers\developers = developers controllers

SAME IN VIEW FILES

> -> application\view\  = front end controllers
>
> -> application\view\admin = superadmin controllers
>
> -> application\view\developers = developers controllers

I am attaching my “.htaccess” file along

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Please anyone can guide me !!!

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Ok, what is your issue?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CDxi2veP

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure, '**config/autoload.php**'

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

then you can redirect easily with

```
redirect('/your-redirect-path/', 'refresh');
```

Comment: CODE : pastebin.com/CDxi2veP
URL : http://hyperlinkserver.com/myappstore/admin/Admin_User/login

Comment: $autoload['helper'] = array('url','form');

Comment: Before redirect(), you have need to check  echo '<pre>';
var_dump($data);
exit; and second thing, in 'autoload.php' session library is loaded ? $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'xmlrpc','ion_auth','pagination','encrypt');

Comment: sounds great, but what var_dump return for $data? and session set properly?

Comment: Test simplest redirect in controller, or if you think, its some kind of problem with hosting environment, just test on 'localhost',

Comment: on this LINK : http://hyperlinkserver.com/
you will fine server configuration of PHP

Comment: what about header("Location: "); ?

Comment: in login view, edit login form, and rename url 'Admin_User/login' as 'admin_user/login', and try to submit, maybe its case insensitive issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can't figure out your issue but if you want to redirect, load url helper with

`$this->load->helper('url');`

& redirect user with

```
redirect('Desired URL OR Controller/function');
```

For more information, follow codeigniter documentation.

Comment: $autoload['helper'] = array('url','form');

Comment: Add constructor in your class, `{
            parent::__construct();
           $this->load->helper('url');
       }` & check

Answer (score 0):

hey Uresh redirect() using this we can redirecting in codeigniter it is the url helper you should be load the

`$this->load->helper('url');`

other wise you can put in the 'config/autoload.php'

```
 $autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

example:

```
$logged_in = your session data
if ($logged_in == FALSE)
{
     redirect('/controllers/admin');
}
```

url helper link [get the helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)